# Is there a way to check answer rate week by week for a given tag?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I am noticing a significant drop in the number of my questions that get answers.  (Good or otherwise)

I am wondering if I am asking harder questions, or if the turmoil of the last 6 months has caught up with Stack Overflow.

**Is there a way to find out, for a given tag, how many questions got answers (or just how many answers) were posted week over week?**

Comment: Usually this is where we ask Shog for stats...

Comment: This is probably something you could glean from a SEDE query. rene is pretty good at those ;).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1210483?tagname=entity-framework#graph) shows the number of answers posted to questions for a specific tag each week:

```sql
select dateadd(week, datepart(week,a.creationdate) , concat(year(a.creationdate),'-01-01')) [date] 
     , count(*) [answers]
from posts q
inner join posts a on a.parentid = q.id
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = q.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where t.tagname = ##tagname:string?tfs##
group by dateadd(week, datepart(week,a.creationdate) , concat(year(a.creationdate),'-01-01'))
order by dateadd(week, datepart(week,a.creationdate) , concat(year(a.creationdate),'-01-01'))
```

Here is the graph for entity-framework:

[image]

SEDE is updated  on Sunday morning.
Let's never forget that [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) wrote the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).
Say "Hi!" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede)

Comment: That is an amazing query!  Thank you!  (And the stats show that it is just me, not the tag, that is having issues getting answers.)